# Fastest way to restore database in postgresql in windows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.4

Hello experts I need a help in postgresql. I am using postgresql from past 4 years now database is 9 GB in size. It takes more than 36 hour to restore in windows server which has 128 GB RAM with ssd hard drive.I worried about it because if in future when server stopped accidentally and it takes more than 36 hour how can I handle my clients? I am using lots of materialize views.

Comment: Use of replication and switch server?

Comment: 9 GB is smallish. Can you check if the time is spend creating the materialized views (check in `pg_stat_activity` what the restore is currently doing)?

Comment: Ok sir i will check

Comment: If you don't mind.. Is there any option to restore database without refreshing matviews or with No data?